# Update multiple data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio

I have 15 data extensions. All of the data extensions have 2 important columns (OpenId, ContactId)

I need to update ContactId against OpenId for all Data Extensions.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can build an Automation with a SQL Query for each Data Extension. If that is not the answer you are looking for, please specify your problem.

Regards,
Christian